# How to asynchronously modify an array of Strings

Tags: java, multithreading, string

I thought this was an interesting programming problem so I posted it even though I think I have a solution idea that is good enough, see (*). If anyone has an elegant solution I would love to see it!

I am working with a method that calls external library that does http requests to a server. I need to have K strings as input to be effective i.e. each invocation of the external resource is a HTTP request and I need to buffer up some data for effectiveness. (As an example let K be 200 and occurs as a token in a text with say 1% probability so I would need to process 20,000 tokens before finding the 200 input arguments).

Effectively what this does is: externalHTTP(commaDelimitedString) -> get info about each string. Example externalHTTP("foo,bar") -> ["information snippet 1","information snippet 2"]. Where "information snippet 1" is about "foo".

I want to replace the "foo" and "bar" in a long text (string) with the information snippets but only after my buffer for the HTTP request is full. I still want to continue reading the original string while waiting for this to happen.

The text is tokenized by splitting (so I am working with an array of strings).

I.e. I would not like to stop execution of my text processing just because I am waiting for K strings to buffer up.

At first I thought that I could store words as individual string objects that I later update but then I realized that strings are immutable so it is call by value.

(*) My second idea was to store indices of the words (foo and bar) and then in order insert the snippets back into the original string array when the http request is finished. Like

```
class doStuff { 

    String text[];
    LinkedList<Integer> idxList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public doStuff(String[] t) {

        text = t;
        int i = 0;
        for (String token : text) {
            if (shouldReplaceToken(token)) {
                replaceToken(i);   
            }
            i++;
           //do other work with the tokens
        }
    }


    void replaceToken(int i) {

        idxList.add(i);
        if (++count > buffSize) {
            count = 0;
            String commaDelim = "";
            ListIterator<Integer> it = idxList.getListIterator(0);
            while (it.hasNext()) {
               commaDelim += text[it.next()]+",";
            }       
            String[] http_response = http_req(commaDelim);
            for (String snippet : http_response) {
                idx = idxList.poll(); //this is not elegant, dependent on FIFO order 
                text[Idx] = snippet;
            } 
        } 
    }

}
```

To complicate things further is that I want to process several longer texts so i would have need to have a matrix of String arrays, one for each text.

I don't like the class known reference

```
String[] text
```

or they way I deal with indices in this code...

Hoping to see some suggestions :)

Edit: changed a bit to be more clear. I cant really say what I am looking up, non-disclosure etc, sorry. Some names might be different from java (bit only small difference).

Comment: Your description of the problem is hard to understand.  Please try to edit the question so it's easier for outsiders to follow.  Assume we know nothing and be clear and descriptive about what you want to do.  A specific example would be helpful.

Comment: Even the first sentence is impossible to understand: _I am working with a method that calls external resources that need to have K strings as input to be effective i.e. each invocation of the external resource is a HTTP request and I need to buffer up some data for effectiveness._  What does `K strings` mean?  The phrase `buffer up some data for effectiveness` does little to explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It is basically about registering listeners with certain substrings that are called when the http request happens. Compare with a asynchronous event.

Comment: I'm sorry for my original question wording, thanks for your input jahroy.

Comment: OK, let me see if I follow...  You get a big array of strings as input.  You want to iterate over that array and use a method to check whether or not a string should be _replaced_.  If so, its index is added to the end of a list.  Once the list hits a certain threshold, a call is made to a web page, which returns an array of strings that should be used to replace the original strings.  Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes that's right! Ideally I do not want to keep track of indices, only the strings themselves.

Comment: Just edited my answer to attempt to show how to do this asynchronously... In other words, how to make it so you don't stop have to stop processing the word list while you're waiting for the HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... Here's an attempt to fully answer your question with example code.

I've never played with threads much, so I figured I'd try to learn something tonight.

This solution uses threads to allow the http request to take place asynchronously.

The asynchronous request is simulated by using [Thread.sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).

My test case is primitive: the main class just sleeps for 30 sec to wait for everything to finish up.

Like I said, I'm new to Thread programming, so I probably overlooked something.

Hopefully this gets you started in the right direction...

```
/**
 *  A class that asynchronously replaces text in an
 *  array of strings by using helper threads.
 */

public class TextReplacer {

    private final int bufferSize;

    List<String>   wordList        =  new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer>  indexList       =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int            bufferPosition  =  0;
    int            lastPosition    =  0;

    public TextReplacer(String[] a, int n) {
        bufferSize = n;
        if (a != null) {
            wordList = Arrays.asList(a);
        }
    }

    public void replaceText() {
        int i = 0;
        for (String thisWord : getWordListCopy()) {
            if (shouldReplaceToken(thisWord)) {
                indexList.add(i);
                processTextReplacement();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void processTextReplacement() {
        if (isBufferReady()) {
            int currentPos = lastPosition;
            replaceStrings(getCsv(), currentPos);
        }
    }

    /** Uses a thread to replace strings in wordList. */

    private void replaceStrings(String csv, int pos) {
        new ReplacerThread(wordList, indexList, csv, pos, bufferSize).start();
    }

    private String getCsv() {
        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i ++) {
            int idx = indexList.get(lastPosition++);
            csv.append(wordList.get(idx)).append(",");
        }
        return csv.toString();
    }

    private boolean isBufferReady() {
        bufferPosition++;
        return ( bufferPosition % bufferSize == 0 );
    }

    private List<String> getWordListCopy() {
        List<String> listCopy = new ArrayList<String>();
        listCopy.addAll(wordList);
        return listCopy;
    }

   /**
    *  Simulates a 10% replacement rate by only
    *  returning true for input that ends with a 3.
    */

    private boolean shouldReplaceToken(String s) {
        return s.endsWith("3");
    }

    public List<String> getWordList() {
        return wordList;
    }

    public String[] getWordArray() {
        return wordList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

}


/**
 *  A thread that sleeps for up to 8 seconds, then
 *  replaces a bunch of words in the list that is
 *  passed to it in its constructor.
 */

public class ReplacerThread extends Thread {

    List<String> originalWords;
    List<Integer> indices;
    String wordCsv;
    String[] replacementWords;
    int startPos;
    int bufferSize;
    int maxSleepMillis = 8000;
    int sleepMillis = getSleepMillis();
    int threadNum;                          // for debugging
    String prefix = new String();           // for debugging

    /** Create a new thread. */

    public ReplacerThread(List<String> o, List<Integer> i, 
                          String c, int p, int n) {
        originalWords = o;
        indices = i;
        wordCsv = c;
        startPos = p;
        bufferSize = n;
        threadNum = startPos / bufferSize;
        int count = 0;
        while (count++ < threadNum) {
            prefix += "   ";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        replacementWords = httpReq(wordCsv);
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i ++) {
            int pos = startPos + i;
            int idx = indices.get(pos);
            originalWords.set(idx, replacementWords[i]);
        }
        print("Thread #" + threadNum + " COMPLETE");
    }

    /** Simulate an asynchronous http request by using Thread.sleep */

    private String[] httpReq(String s) {
        try { 
            printSleepMessage();
            sleep(sleepMillis);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        String[] repText = s.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < repText.length; i++) {
            repText[i] = repText[i].replace("Line", "Funky Line");
        }
        return repText;
    }

    private void printSleepMessage() {
        int ms = sleepMillis / 1000;
        print("Thread #" + threadNum + " SLEEP(" + ms + ")");
    }

    private int getSleepMillis() {
        Double ms = maxSleepMillis * Math.random();
        return ms.intValue();
    }

    public void print(Object o) {
        String s = (o == null ? "null" : o.toString());
        System.out.println(prefix + s + "\n");
    }

}

/** A class that tests my funky solution. */

public class Main {

    static String inputFile = "test-input.txt";
    static int bufferSize = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] theInput = readInput();
        TextReplacer testItem = new TextReplacer(theInput, bufferSize);
        testItem.replaceText();
        try {
            // wait 40 seconds for everything to happen
            Thread.sleep(40000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
        dumpOutput(testItem.getWordArray());
    }

    public static String[] readInput() {
        File inFile = new File(inputFile);
        List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
            String currentLine = buff.readLine();
            while (currentLine != null) {
                lineList.add(currentLine);
                currentLine = buff.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ignoreMe) {}
        print("Lines read:    " + lineList.size());
        return lineList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static void dumpOutput(String[] txt) {
        long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String fileName = "output-" + ms + ".txt";
        File outFile = new File(fileName);
        try {
            BufferedWriter buff = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
            for (String s : txt) {
                buff.write(s);
                buff.newLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ignoreMe) {}
        print("Lines written: " + txt.length);
        print("File:          " + fileName);
    }

    public static void print(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o == null ? "null" : o.toString());
    }

}
```